# Using 3d scanned textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, point-clouds

I have been debating on purchasing a 3D scanner to make point cloud references of objects to model for games. For example, use the scanner to create a point cloud object of a character, then import the point cloud into blender and model around it to create a polygon mesh. This part I'm clear on. My dilemma lies within extracting the texture of the scanned point cloud image for use on the polygon mesh. Does anyone know how one could go about this, or if something of this nature is doable?

Comment: Why have it export to a point cloud? Why not a full on 3D scan? From there you could retopologize it and you're have easier to see infomation than you would from a point cloud. You'd probably also get the texture info also (you'd have to correct it to fit the UV map of the retopologized object though). Just keep in mind that 3D scanned textures are usually pretty low resolution.

Comment: I am going to be looking into this retopologizing. I had no idea of it's existence until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](https://blog.sketchfab.com/retopologise-3d-scans-low-poly-game-assets/) explains how to retopologize a mesh and bake the normal maps from the hi-polygon mesh to the low polygon mesh. This was exactly what I was looking for, but didn't know what the process was called (baking normal maps).

[Another blog post](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/bake-normal-maps.php) that goes into greater detail on baking normal maps.

I would also like to thank @TARDIS Maker for pointing out that 3D scans could be done as a full on mesh and not only point clouds, AND for shining the light of retopologizing hi-res meshes. I had no idea this process existed.